# What is the best version of OpenCV perfectly compatible with VS 2012?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

What is the best version of OpenCV perfectly compatible with Visual Studio 2012 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try OpenCV 2.4.10 or 2.4.6(tested)
You can get almost all features on this version.